# I'm worried about/for you

Tags: word-choice

> I've asked to talk to you because I'm worried about/for you.

1. Does the sentence with "about" and "for" mean the exact same thing?
2. I can see that "about" is much more common than "for", but would there be situations where "for" would be preferred?

Comment: No, there are no situations in which *for* would be preferred (unless it's some dialectal difference -- not sure what BrE uses).

Comment: @FeliniusRex: I disagree, as does the answer to this question when asked previously. If ***I worry about Fred***, I might not care in the least whether Fred himself suffers - perhaps all that worries me is that Fred might do something that harms people I ***do*** care about. But if ***I worry for Fred***, that unambiguously indicates I'm concerned about *Fred's* wellbeing. And I can't believe that's only a *British* English distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1. Worry "for" is a concern for the welfare of someone. Worry "about" might include that, or it might mean I see a threat from Fred to me or to something else.